# How do i build array of regions?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

The array should contain 3 regions.
Each region should include two numbers :

region 1 for example will contain 3,4
region 2 5,5
region 3 23,100

Comment: `int region[][] = {{3,4}, {5,5}, {23,100}};`

Comment: Please, explain your concept of `region`, as above it seems more a `Point`

Comment: Please read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), and come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Three-dimensional array. 
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                             { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Which was taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), which I found using [Google](http://www.google.com/) and searching with this string, "multidimensional arrays in C#".